Try-catch block where managing exceptions could cause error
I have a School class which includes avl trees: one for students, another for emptyClasses, and another for nonEmptyclasses.
The function I'm struggling with looks like this: (status is an enum such that 0=succes,1=allocation_error,3=failure,4=invalid=input):
Status leave_class(int studentId){
   //check validity of input
   try{
      if(numStudents==1){
         #remove class from nonEmptyClasses
         #add class to emptyClasses
      }
      Class->removeStudent(studentId)
   }
   catch(...){
      Return status::allocation_error
   }
   Students->leave() //this line changes student fields to ints of 0 and nullptr for pointers
   Return status::successs
}

The 3 actions in the try block could throw exceptions/errors, but then in the catch block if I try to reverse the error that happened then the reversing process could also be prone to the same errors.
For example, if I succeeded in removing a class from nonEmptyClasses and failed to add it in the emptyClasses, I have to reverse the removal which could also end up with an error.
I thought of separating the actions into multiple functions, or using mltiple try blocks, but I keep going back to square 1.
Any recommendations?

Look up techniques to ensure a "strong exception safety guarantee".

You could ensure those operations don't allocate memory and thus cannot throw. E.g. rather than deallocating the node in remove and allocating a new one in add, you can reuse the same node, moving it from one tree to the other. A la std::map::extract.

If your remove action can cause an allocation error, you are doing it wrong.

In principle there is nothing wrong with having an exception in a catch block. You handle it at an upper level as normal.

You could do all work on copies of the actual data and if everything goes well, you move the new data to the old data (commit). This move should not be able to fail. If something goes wrong, you discard the copied data.

Here are some pointers to how you could cleanup your code and add exception to status translations.
#include <stdexcept>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

enum class Status
{
    Succes,
    AllocationError,
    Failure,
    InvalidInput
};

// You can have a reusable function for translating exceptions to your
// status code. 
Status TranslateException()
{
    try
    {
        throw;
    }
    catch(const std::invalid_argument&) // <== replace this with your exception types
    {
        return Status::InvalidInput;
    }
    catch(const std::bad_alloc& )
    {
        return Status::AllocationError;
    }
    catch(std::exception&) // All exceptions should be derived from a base exception
    {
        return Status::Failure;
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        std::exit(-1); // This should really not happen
    }

    return Status::Succes;
};


// When dealing with exceptions Scopeguards are a very useful pattern 
// this class will in its destructor call a function.
// This is useful because if your function leaves a scope (through an exception)
// a scopeguard instantiated in that scope will be deleted 
// and its destructor will be called. Allowing you to do things.
template<typename fn_t>
class ScopeGuard
{
public:
    ScopeGuard(fn_t undo_function) : 
        m_undo_function{undo_function)
    {
    }

    ~ScopeGuard()
    {
        if (m_active) 
        {
            m_fn();
        }
    }

    // If you are at a point that
    // everything went will you can
    // release the guard (kind of like a transaction commit)
    void Release()
    {
        m_active = false;
    }

private:
    bool m_active{true};
    fn_t m_undo_function;
};

// Now you can implement your function something like this
Status leave_class(int studentId)
{
    std::size_t numStudents{1ul};

    try
    {
        ScopeGuard undoRemoveFromNonEmptyClass = []{ std::cout << "Undo remove from non empty class here...\n" };
        ScopeGuard undoAddToEmptyClass = []{ std::cout << "Undo Add to empty class here...\n" };
        
        nonEmptyClasses.Remove(); 
        undoRemoveFromNonEmptyClass.Release();

        emptyClasses.Add();
        undoAddToEmptyClass.Release();

        Students->leave() //this line changes student fields to ints of 0 and nullptr for pointers
    }
    catch(const std::exception&)
    {
        return TranslateException();
    }
   
   return status::successs
}


Unless you are dealing with C code or some other code that cannot have C++ exceptions, is there any point at all in translating exceptions to status codes? Just handle exceptions throughout. You have already paid the price for having them.

@n.m.couldbeanAI Not really but I followed OP's problem statement.  Note I use this kind of code (more evolved) when moving from C++ to say gRPC or COM (which indeed need translation from exceptions to return codes).  The ScopeGuard concept however is always useful in the presence of exceptions :)
